# Share source code between Elastic Beanstalk environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to share source code in two EB environments and modules/components seem a perfect way to do this. Modules allow for multiple env configurations in one repo - I just put it in a dedicated folder. Unfortunately it also seems that it forces all the code in the dedicated folder so I'd end up with duplicated code...

Documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html) says

> Each subfolder contains the source code for an independent component of an application that will run in its own environment

Any ideas how to get past this?